# how do i find the list of ecmascript versions supported by a typescript versoin?

Tags: javascript, typescript

My application is using **Typescript 2.5.3**, i wanted to use **ES2020** features, can i add **ES2020** libraries (to *lib* in `tsconfig.json`) and compile it to target **ES5** ? .

How do we know which **ES** libraries are supported by *2.5.3 version*?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `ES2020` features and have them compile to ES5, you can include the following in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "lib": "ES2020",
  "target": "ES5",
}
```

[`lib` configuration documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib)

[`target` configuration documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target)

`lib` has been around since the 2.0 release and `target` has been around since the `1.0` release, so I believe you should be safe to use those. As for how to view the available values, you should be able to run `tsc --help` and the available values will be listed for you (tested with version `2.5.3`):

```
--lib                                              Specify library files to be included in the compilation: 
                                                      'es5' 'es6' 'es2015' 'es7' 'es2016' 'es2017' 'esnext' 'dom' 'dom.iterable' 'webworker' 'scripthost' 'es2015.core' 'es2015.collection' 'es2015.generator' 'es2015.iterable' 'es2015.promise' 'es2015.proxy' 'es2015.reflect' 'es2015.symbol' 'es2015.symbol.wellknown' 'es2016.array.include' 'es2017.object' 'es2017.sharedmemory' 'es2017.string' 'es2017.intl' 'esnext.asynciterable'
```

```
-t VERSION, --target VERSION                       Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'.
```

In an ideal world, the TypeScript documentation would be versioned and so you could see all the available configuration options and values for older versions.

Worst comes to worst, you can download the source code (e.g. [version 2.5.3 found here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/releases/tag/v2.5.3)) for the version of interest and look into the source code to see the available options.

Comment: "*Your TypeScript compiler will likely let you know if you're using an unsupported lib or target.*" I thought that was the question - how do you know without waiting for an error during compilation.

Comment: @Robert Cooper thanks for the response, so there is no way that we could know prior to compilation which libraries and targets are allowed to use for a typescript version?, just wondering why this is not captured in the documentation..

Comment: @sureshnomula Actually, you can run `tsc --help` and the available values will be listed in the help message. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Rober Cooper thanks for updating the answer, now it is clear to me